# Stylus mixins as class names

Tags: css, class, less, mixins, stylus

With Less I can do the following:

```css
/* less code */
.grid {
    display: grid;
}

#my-element {
    .grid();
}

/* Yields:
*
* #my-element {
*     display: grid;
* }
*/
```

But I can use `.grid` also in html in any element of my choice, e.g.:

```html
<div class="grid">...
```

Less has the advantage of allowing double usage of mixins:  mixins like the one in my example can also be used to define classes.

Is there a **way** to do the **same** with **Stylus**? I warmly thank you in advance for you help!

Comment: I wanted to add that, even if the solution I've found (see my answer below) is ok, I'm still looking for a way to achieve what I've asked, that is: having a mixin that can be use as a mixin (obviously) and as a class name.
With Less I need one definition `.mydef { prop: value; }`, then I can use this in another css defs (like `h1 { .mydef(); }`, and as a class name in my html (like `<section class="mydef">....</section>`).
Where Less requires one step to achieve that goal, Stylus requires two.
Still looking for a way to do that with Stylus in one step only... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've found...:

```css
/* Stylus code */
grid =
  display flex

.grid
  {grid}

/* Yields
*
* .grid {
*   display: flex;
* }
*/
```

Now I can use the block `{grid}` to define properties of other css elements, and I can use the class `grid` with html elements as well.

I can set the property `display: flex;` to any other element I want in my css, and I can also use the class `grid` in my html (e.g.: `<div class="grid">....`.

If you know better way(s) (more close to what I asked in my question), please let me know! Thanks.

Ps: of course it's a minimalist example, but you get the idea.